# unable to resolve undeclared identifier error for CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA

Tags: mfc, visual-c++, visual-studio-6

as per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I am supposed to include "Shlobj.h" for CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA to run, but I am still getting `error C2065: 'CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA' : undeclared identifier` 
the line that causes the error is

`if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetSpecialFolderPathA(NULL,szPath,CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA,FALSE)))`

can any one help? I am coding in vc++ using Visual Studio 6.0

Comment: If you open shlobj.h is CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA actually defined?

Comment: yes that's exactly what msdn says!

Comment: I know that's what it says but just to ensure you have the correct version of shlobj.h you should open it and validate that the #define is there. It should read: #define CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA            0x0023

Comment: well I did that, this is what the line in shlobj.h reads '#define CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA 35'

Comment: Is there a conditional define above it, e.g. #if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_VISTA)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an invalid (or old) version of shlobj.h. Download the latest SDK from Microsoft and it will have the latest version of that file:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Comment: do you think that's a good idea? wont it hamper any other functionalities?

Comment: I posted that answer before you corrected your comment on what your CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA was defined as. Try moving the shlobj.h include to the top of the CPP file and see if that helps.